# Adding Results to a List and Setting up a for-loop

Tags: python, for-loop, differential-equations, calculus

For a school assignment, I am coding an algorithm that computes slopes using the Euler method. In part of it, I have a for loop that will repeat a pattern of equations until the end result is met. What I need is a way to add each result to a list and then afterwards plot each item in the list. I also need some help setting up the for-loop if possible.

Here's what I have, keeping in mind I am very inexperienced at coding (please bear with me)

```
stpsz = input ("Define "h" Value (step size)")
tfinal = input ("Define Final "T" Value (stopping place)")
xnow = input ("Define "X0" as a Starting Value")

t = 0
while t > tfinal
    t = t + 1
    slopenow = (xnow * (1-xnow))

#Save slopenow (as a number, not variable) to a list of slopes ( I don't understand how to make a list like this)
#Save xnow (as a number, not variable) to a list of xs)

    xnext = (slopenow * stpsz)+(xnow)
    xnext = x now

#repeat while-loop until tfinal is reached)
```

I greatly appreciate whatever help you all can give.

Comment: I think you should start by figuring out what your `xnext` in you equation is and how it would look like in the equation `f(t1)`. You need to find a pattern in the equations and the for loop or a recursion is probably easy ;)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am interested, just not entirely understanding.

Comment: You might want to clarify, which Euler method you are referring to (he was quite prolific) and what `tfinal` represents. If it is really just the number of iterations for your process, please accept the answer from @blues below.

Comment: what I'm saying is you should start by writing down the full equation (with  numbers) for the first step (t_0) and then for the second step (t_1). If you have done this you'll see what are the variables that change, the variables that have a dependency to the previous step and so on. If you have found the pattern you'll see the for loop, while loop or whatever automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds what you are looking for is a `while` loop. Like this:

```
t = 0
while t < 10:
    t = t + 1
    # more code here
```

Comment: That makes sense for the T part. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an recursive approach for [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) equation, to give you an idea what I meant in my comment.

```
class Slope:
    def __init__(self, timestamp, slope):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.slope = slope


def find_slope(slopes, slope, step_size, until):
    if slope.timestamp > until:
        return slopes
    current_y = slope.slope + step_size * slope.slope
    slope = Slope(slope.timestamp + 1, current_y)
    slopes.append(slope)
    return find_slope(slopes, slope, step_size, until)

if __name__=="__main__":
    initial_slope = Slope(0, 1)
    for current in find_slope([], initial_slope, 1, 3):
        print("slope: {slope}, timestamp: {timestamp}".format(**current.__dict__))
```

But there multiple ways to solve this problem e.g. with a while or a for loop. I also have to admit you could write a shorter version but I think the verbosity helps you better understand.

**Edit**

Your eyes should focus on that function...

```
def find_slope(slopes, slope, step_size, until):
    if slope.timestamp > until:
        return slopes
    current_y = slope.slope + step_size * slope.slope
    slope = Slope(slope.timestamp + 1, current_y)
    slopes.append(slope)
    return find_slope(slopes, slope, step_size, until)
```

This is a [recursive](https://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php) call or simpler a function that calls itself as long as a certain point is reached here it is `if slope.timestamp > until`. The first call is with my `initial_slope` (`step_size` and `until` are just constants).

The line `current_y = slope.slope + step_size * slope.slope` calculates the new slope value. Then I create a slope instance with the new slope value and updated time and add it to a list.

The slope instance, the slope list and the constants are passed into the next step with a self call of the function `return find_slope(slopes, slope, step_size, until)`. The return is needed to not only go down the ladder and collect new slopes but also return back to the start so the caller can receive it.

You can call the recursive function with

```
 slopes = find_slope([], initial_slope, 1, 3)
```

and get a list of slopes back. I initialized it with an empty list that will be filled with slopes and later be returned from this function.

Comment: Wow, thank you! From what I understand of that I see that it is the type of method I am working with. Unfortunately, I don't understand it very well. If it's not a great inconvenience to you could you please explain the different parts a bit more and how they relate to what I was trying to do? I see that you are using a slope class which I now am definitely going to incorporate, I'm just not sure how.  Thank you.

Comment: @NoahSprenger does this help?